# How to create conditionals in a document class for latex?

Tags: packages, conditionals

I am trying to write a document class `highschool.cls` for the high school research papers in our school based on the `book.cls` in order to make the format of the papers standardized. I am trying to define a signature page with heading ``CERTIFICATION'' such that the following text appears on the page.

[image]

To achieve this, I made the following definitions on LaTeX class `highschool.cls`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{highschool}
                      [2012/08/22 v0.1e
         Standard LaTeX document class]

\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@surnamea  \@surnameafalse
\newif\if@surnameb  \@surnamebfalse
\newif\if@surnamec  \@surnamecfalse
\newif\if@firstnamea    \@firstnameafalse
\newif\if@firstnameb    \@firstnamebfalse
\newif\if@firstnamec    \@firstnamecfalse
\newif\if@midinitiala    \@midinitialafalse
\newif\if@midinitialb    \@midinitialbfalse
\newif\if@midinitialc    \@midinitialcfalse

\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
\setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}%
\setlength\textwidth   {6in}%

\def\defenseDate#1{\gdef\@defensedate{#1}}
\def\surnamea#1{\gdef\@surnamea{#1}}
\def\firstnamea#1{\gdef\@firstnamea{#1}}
\def\midinitiala#1{\gdef\@midinitiala{#1}}
\def\surnameb#1{\gdef\@surnameb{#1}}
\def\firstnameb#1{\gdef\@firstnameb{#1}}
\def\midinitialb#1{\gdef\@midinitialb{#1}}
\def\surnamec#1{\gdef\@surnamec{#1}}
\def\firstnamec#1{\gdef\@firstnamec{#1}}
\def\midinitialc#1{\gdef\@midinitialc{#1}}

\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else \DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}} \fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\ExecuteOptions{12pt,oneside,final,openright} 
\ProcessOptions
\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}

\def\signaturep{ %% signature page..
   \topmargin 0in \headsep 0in
   \begin{center}
   \textbf{CERTIFICATION}\\[6pt]
   \end{center}
   This is to certify that this research paper entitled,
   \textbf{``{\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}}''} and submitted by
  \textbf{\uppercase\expandafter{\@firstnamea} \uppercase\expandafter{\@midinitiala}. \uppercase\expandafter{\@surnamea}}, \textbf{\uppercase\expandafter{\@firstnameb} \uppercase\expandafter{\@midinitialb}. \uppercase\expandafter{\@surnameb}}, and \textbf{\uppercase\expandafter{\@firstnamec} \uppercase\expandafter{\@midinitialc}. \uppercase\expandafter{\@surnamec}} 
   to fulfill part of the requirements for
   the course Science and Technology Research II was successfully
   defended and approved on \expandafter{\@defensedate}.
}%% signature page

\def\prelim{%%prelim page
\typeout{Making SMCT preliminary headings...}%
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \signaturep \newpage
   \baselineskip=20pt
} %%prelim

\endinput
```

In my source TeX file,  I would type something like

```
\documentclass{highschool}

\defenseDate{18 August 2012}
\title{This is the Title of the Paper}
\surnamea{Author}
\firstnamea{First}
\midinitiala{N}
\surnameb{Author}
\firstnameb{Second}
\midinitialb{N}
\surnamec{Author}
\firstnamec{Third}
\midinitialc{N}

\begin{document}
\prelim %% Prints Preliminary chapters

\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is that

- when there are no `\surnameb,\firstnameb,\midinitialb,\surnamec,\firstnamec,` and `\midinitialc` declared, I get the following text:

[image]

- when there are no `\surnamec,\firstnamec,` and `\midinitialc` declared, I get the following text:

[image]

- and when all are declared, I get the text:
  [image]

Is it possible to do this? If it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following solution is based on these assumptions:

1. You can only have

   - *Author 1*; or
   - *Author 1*, and *Author 2*; or
   - *Author 1*, *Author 2*, and *Author 3*

   and not, for example

   - *Author 1*, and *Author 3*; or
   - *Author 2*, and *Author 3*; or
   - *Author 2* only; or
   - *Author 3* only.
2. It is sufficient to supply only a first name to distinguish whether an author "exists" or not.

The second condition can be modified, but it seemed logical that one would have a first name *and* a surname and *possibly* a middle initial, but never *not* a first name. Consequently, you can then use the following definitions:

```
\def\defenseDate#1{\gdef\@defensedate{#1}}
\def\surnamea#1{\gdef\@surnamea{#1}\@surnameatrue}
\def\firstnamea#1{\gdef\@firstnamea{#1}\@firstnameatrue}
\def\midinitiala#1{\gdef\@midinitiala{#1}\@midinitialatrue}
\def\surnameb#1{\gdef\@surnameb{#1}\@surnamebtrue}
\def\firstnameb#1{\gdef\@firstnameb{#1}\@firstnamebtrue}
\def\midinitialb#1{\gdef\@midinitialb{#1}\@midinitialbtrue}
\def\surnamec#1{\gdef\@surnamec{#1}\@surnamectrue}
\def\firstnamec#1{\gdef\@firstnamec{#1}\@firstnamectrue}
\def\midinitialc#1{\gdef\@midinitialc{#1}\@midinitialctrue}

\def\signaturep{ %% signature page..
  \topmargin 0in \headsep 0in
  \begin{center}
  \textbf{CERTIFICATION}\\[6pt]
  \end{center}
  This is to certify that this research paper entitled,
  \textbf{``{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}''} and submitted by
  \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@firstnamea} \MakeUppercase{\@midinitiala}.\ \MakeUppercase{\@surnamea}}%
  \if@firstnameb, \if@firstnamec\else and \fi
  \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@firstnameb} \MakeUppercase{\@midinitialb}.\ \MakeUppercase{\@surnameb}}\if@firstnamec, \else\space\fi
  \if@firstnamec and \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@firstnamec} \MakeUppercase{\@midinitialc}.\ \MakeUppercase{\@surnamec}} \fi\else\space\fi
  to fulfill part of the requirements for
  the course Science and Technology Research II was successfully
  defended and approved on \expandafter{\@defensedate}.
}%% signature page
```

I've added the conditional definitions inside each of the respective author components (this is not really necessary, since only `\if@firstnameX` is used) and placed the conditions throughout `\signaturep` to include/exclude certain words/phrases/punctuation based on the truth of the conditions.

The input

```
\documentclass{highschool}

\defenseDate{18 August 2012}
\title{This is the Title of the Paper}
\surnamea{Author}
\firstnamea{First}
\midinitiala{N}
\surnameb{Author}
\firstnameb{Second}
\midinitialb{N}
%\surnamec{Author}
%\firstnamec{Third}
%\midinitialc{N}

\begin{document}
\prelim %% Prints Preliminary chapters

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

---

The following minimal example adds an option to specify the list of authors as a single macro `\listauthors{{<first>},{<second>},{<third>},...}` using a CSV list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\def\@firstmiddlelast#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \gdef\@firstname{#1}% Extract first name
  \gdef\@middlename{#2}% Extract middle name
  \gdef\@lastname{#3}% Extract last name
}
\newcommand{\authorfml}{{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@firstname\ \@middlename\unskip\ \@lastname}}}% First Middle Last
\newcommand{\authorlfm}{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@middlename\unskip}% Last, First Middle
\newcommand{\authorseq}{\authorfml}% Default author order
\newcounter{@list@item}\newcounter{@total@item}
\newcommand{\listauthors}[1]{%
  \setcounter{@total@item}{0}% Reset total count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{@total@item}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}% Count number of items in list
  \setcounter{@list@item}{1}% Start at first item
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{@list@item}% Move to next item
    \@firstmiddlelast##1\@nil% Extract first/middle/last names
    \authorseq% Print author names
    \ifnum\value{@list@item}=\value{@total@item}\relax
      , and % Second-to-last name
    \else
      \ifnum\value{@list@item}<\value{@total@item}\relax
        , % First set of names
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}% Print list
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
See \listauthors{{First1,Middle1,Last1},{First2,,Last2},{First3,Middle3,Last3},
  {First4,Middle4,Last4},{First5,,Last5},{First6,Middle6,Last6},
  {First7,Middle7,Last7},{First8,Middle8,Last8},{First9,,Last9}} from first to last. \par
\renewcommand{\authorseq}{\authorlfm}
See \listauthors{{First1,Middle1,Last1},{First2,,Last2},{First3,Middle3,Last3}} from first to last. \par
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\authorseq` determines how the titles are printed. `\authorseq` defaults to `\authorfml` which prints the author list as `<first name>\ <middle name>\unskip\ <last name>` (`\unskip` takes care of missing/non-existent `<middle name>` in removing the preceding control space `\`). Switching around the author display (for use in your abstract and introduction, if needed) is done by a redefinition of `\authorseq`, while formatting is controlled within the macros used (`\authorfml` or `\authorlfm` or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @Werner. Indeed, your first assumption fits my problem very well.

Comment: I am now going to accept this as the answer. My implementation was for more than ten authors and I could say that my code was a lot on the side of ugly at this point, but it works, and does not give errors. I wonder though how to do it with the second condition? (Or should I post it as another question?) Thank you.

Comment: @hpesoj626: There are better ways of doing this. For example, it would be possible to create a macro where you just list the authors `\authorlist{First A.\ Author, Second B.\ Author, Third C.\ Author}` which translates to **First A. Author**, **Second B. Author** and **Third C. Author**. Would that work? It would help to also know whether you use the declared "author variables" elsewhere in your document.

Comment: I use them in my title page and the abstract page. I defined the surname separate from the first name and middle initial so that the surname will appear first in the abstract page. It would be great though to just write one command to list all authors. How can I do that?

Comment: @hpesoj626: I've updated my answer with a list processing `\listauthors` macro. It may come in handy to shorten your usage within your documents.

Comment: This is perfectly what I need. Thanks for the time going back on this question. I really appreciate it. It's making me think about learning more about TeX. But one thing at a time. I still need to check some papers.